# How to implement PASSWORD() method in MySQL and MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, passwords, mysql-workbench

Can someone explain with a simple code how I can use password() method to take 4 digit integer pin from a user and save it in database in a Password format. 
PS: I know its not a good mechanism to store password without hashing and salting, but at the moment I have to use Password() method only.

So please give me a working understanding how I can store passwords using the above method in MYSQL Workbench.

Comment: The function [Password()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) was never intended to be used to store user passwords, please follow the link and read the "Note" boxes. Furthermore it will be removed in future versions completely. Instead one should use a password-hash function of the development environment, for PHP this would be [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you help me out on how to use aes enrypt and decrypt mysql functions on my hibernate example? I dont know how to use it in Hibernate using @ColumnTransformer Annotation.

Comment: If you think about encrypting the passwords, this would be the wrong way too. Passwords should be hashed not encrypted, I wrote a short tutorial about [secure password storing](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).